# Android: Image Mapping (Multiple Areas)

Tags: java, android, image, imageview, mapping

I am currently using the below code as a basis for image-mapping on Android.

The code works by having a invisible mask of an image with various coloured "hotspots".

[image]

It then uses an OnTouchListener to determine the colour the user has touched, changing the image in doing so e.g. red = image_1, blue = image_2 etc.

The provided code works great and has been a ideal stepping stone for my scenario, however it only allows the user to display one part of the image such as the alien or flames.

[image]

I was wondering if it is possible to display multiple parts of the image map at the same time (Alien & Flames). Sorry if this post has been formatted weird (First time posting)

**ColourTool:**

```
package com.wglxy.example.imageareas;

import android.graphics.Color;

/**
 * A class with methods to help with colors.
 * (Only one method so far.)
 * 
 */

public class ColorTool {

/**
 * Return true if the two colors are a pretty good match.
 * To be a good match, all three color values (RGB) must be within the tolerance value given.
 * 
 * @param color1 int
 * @param color2 int
 * @param tolerance int - the max difference that is allowed for any of the RGB components
 * @return boolean
 */

public boolean closeMatch (int color1, int color2, int tolerance) {
    if ((int) Math.abs (Color.red (color1) - Color.red (color2)) > tolerance ) return false;
    if ((int) Math.abs (Color.green (color1) - Color.green (color2)) > tolerance ) return false;
    if ((int) Math.abs (Color.blue (color1) - Color.blue (color2)) > tolerance ) return false;
    return true;
} // end match

} // end class
```

**ImageAreasActivity:**

```
package com.wglxy.example.imageareas;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * This activity displays an image on the screen. 
 * The image has three different regions that can be clicked / touched.
 * When a region is touched, the activity changes the view to show a different
 * image.
 *
 */

public class ImageAreasActivity extends Activity 
    implements View.OnTouchListener 
{

/**
 * Create the view for the activity.
 *tt
 */

@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.image);
    if (iv != null) {
       iv.setOnTouchListener (this);
    }

    toast ("Touch the screen to discover where the regions are.");
}

/**
 * Respond to the user touching the screen.
 * Change images to make things appear and disappear from the screen.
 *
 */    

public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent ev) 
{
    boolean handledHere = false;

    final int action = ev.getAction();

    final int evX = (int) ev.getX();
    final int evY = (int) ev.getY();
    int nextImage = -1;         // resource id of the next image to display

    // If we cannot find the imageView, return.
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById (R.id.image);
    if (imageView == null) return false;

    // When the action is Down, see if we should show the "pressed" image for the default image.
    // We do this when the default image is showing. That condition is detectable by looking at the
    // tag of the view. If it is null or contains the resource number of the default image, display the pressed image.
    Integer tagNum = (Integer) imageView.getTag ();
    int currentResource = (tagNum == null) ? R.drawable.p2_ship_default : tagNum.intValue ();

    // Now that we know the current resource being displayed we can handle the DOWN and UP events.

    switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
       if (currentResource == R.drawable.p2_ship_default) {
          nextImage = R.drawable.p2_ship_pressed;
          handledHere = true;
       /*
       } else if (currentResource != R.drawable.p2_ship_default) {
         nextImage = R.drawable.p2_ship_default;
         handledHere = true;
       */
       } else handledHere = true;
       break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
       // On the UP, we do the click action.
       // The hidden image (image_areas) has three different hotspots on it.
       // The colors are red, blue, and yellow.
       // Use image_areas to determine which region the user touched.
       int touchColor = getHotspotColor (R.id.image_areas, evX, evY);

       // Compare the touchColor to the expected values. Switch C to a different image, depending on what color was touched.
       // Note that we use a Color Tool object to test whether the observed color is close enough to the real color to
       // count as a match. We do this because colors on the screen do not match the map exactly because of scaling and
       // varying pixel density.
       ColorTool ct = new ColorTool ();;
       int tolerance = 25;
       nextImage = R.drawable.p2_ship_default;
       if (ct.closeMatch (Color.RED, touchColor, tolerance)) nextImage = R.drawable.p2_ship_alien;
       else if (ct.closeMatch (Color.BLUE, touchColor, tolerance)) nextImage = R.drawable.p2_ship_powered;
       else if (ct.closeMatch (Color.YELLOW, touchColor, tolerance)) nextImage = R.drawable.p2_ship_no_star;
       else if (ct.closeMatch (Color.WHITE, touchColor, tolerance)) nextImage = R.drawable.p2_ship_default;


       // toast ("Current image: " + currentResource + " next: " + nextImage);
       if (currentResource == nextImage) {
          nextImage = R.drawable.p2_ship_default;
       } 
       handledHere = true; 
       break;

    default:
       handledHere = false;
    } // end switch

    if (handledHere) {

       if (nextImage > 0) {
          imageView.setImageResource (nextImage);
          imageView.setTag (nextImage);
       }
    }
    return handledHere;
}   

/**
 * Resume the activity.
 */

@Override protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    View v  = findViewById (R.id.wglxy_bar);
    if (v != null) {
       Animation anim1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
       //anim1.setAnimationListener (new StartActivityAfterAnimation (i));
       v.startAnimation (anim1);
    }
}

/**
 * Handle a click on the Wglxy views at the bottom.
 *
 */    

public void onClickWglxy (View v) {
    Intent viewIntent = new Intent ("android.intent.action.VIEW", 
                                    Uri.parse("http://double-star.appspot.com/blahti/ds-download.html"));
    startActivity(viewIntent);

}


/**
 */
// More methods

/**
 * Get the color from the hotspot image at point x-y.
 * 
 */

public int getHotspotColor (int hotspotId, int x, int y) {
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById (hotspotId);
    if (img == null) {
       Log.d ("ImageAreasActivity", "Hot spot image not found");
       return 0;
    } else {
      img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); 
      Bitmap hotspots = Bitmap.createBitmap(img.getDrawingCache()); 
      if (hotspots == null) {
         Log.d ("ImageAreasActivity", "Hot spot bitmap was not created");
         return 0;
      } else {
        img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        return hotspots.getPixel(x, y);
      }
    }
}

/**
 * Show a string on the screen via Toast.
 * 
 * @param msg String
 * @return void
 */

public void toast (String msg)
{
    Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
} // end toast

} // end class
```

Comment: Original Tutorial: https://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/images-with-clickable-areas/

Comment: Progress: I have created transparent versions of each asset (Aliens, Flames...) set them to "Invisible" and then on (if (ct.closeMatch (Color.RED, touchColor, tolerance))) set them to "Visible" but I do not know how to fix the loop allowing the user to click the same asset to remove it like before. Thanks.